# Non-zero probability that detonating a nuclear bomb sets off atmospheric fission chain reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics, atmospheric-science, explosions

After watching Oppenheimer I am under the impression that there is always a non-zero probability that the detonation of an atomic/nuclear bomb will set off a chain reaction of fission in Earth’s atmosphere. Here is the paper written by scientists at that time which ultimately convinced Oppenheimer that the chances of this were extremely minute:

https://blog.nuclearsecrecy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/1946-LA-602-Konopinski-Marvin-Teller-Ignition-fo-the-Atmsophere.pdf

My question is whether or not it remains true that there is a non-zero chance of such a chain reaction. If there is, perhaps the terror of nuclear armageddon is not owed to detonating cities and the consequence of nuclear fallouts, but is instead owed to the ever-present probability each time a bomb explodes that there is a three out of a million chance the detonation does indeed trigger an atmospheric fission chain reaction. The more times the button is pressed, the more bombs explode, the more we test these odds. The more we roll the dice the more likely that remote possibility eventually occurs. Is this where the fear of Armageddon is rightfully placed?

Comment: See, for example, https://www.insidescience.org/manhattan-project-legacy/atmosphere-on-fire - the number you cite is just plain wrong.

Comment: @JonCuster my takeaway from this article is that the atmospheric pressure on Earth is too weak to sustain this reaction as is done in the interior of the sun, where the force of gravity is much stronger and therefore provides more energy for particles to collide with. Correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can open, unsafe nuclear fusion reaction burn the atmosphere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66276/)